# Does a thawed frozen entree rot?

Tags: pasta

I left an Indian cuisine frozen entrée out and I left for two weeks. Will I come home to maggots? I heard Frozen foods can't produce maggots. Please help!

Comment: I assume that "left out" means you left it outside of the freezer, so at room temperature. So the food will simply defrost, making your quesiton a duplicate of any food left out.

Comment: Maggots will only be produced if flies are able to access the food and lay eggs. If it is in a sealed container, then the answer is likely no. However, the food will have rotted/decomposed in the intervening period and is unsafe to eat. For an unsealed container - the answer still depends on fly access and is unanswerable.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I left it out on the counter meaning to cook it but I completely forgot about it. I just worried there would be maggots or a horrible smell

Comment: The point of food safety is not to predict what will happen to the food. It is to tell you whether a government agency is willing to promise you that you won't get sick. If the answer is "No, you don't get that promise, the food is unsafe" the actual state of the food can be anything. Maggots, smell, no noticeable changes, etc. is not really predictable.